# Why the common trend assumption is not testable in the simple two-group two period DID?

Tags: difference-in-difference

From [this paper, page 459](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-publhealth-040617-013507), the author documented that

> In the **simple two-group two-period DID, the common trend assumption is
> not testable**

And

> Visual evidence may be less compelling when the data are noisy or the
> time series is short. In such cases, it may be **difficult to
> distinguish between statistical noise and genuine deviations from the
> common trends**

I am wondering if you can clarify it for me because I think we can plot the lines with three points for each of control and treatment groups in two-group two period DID? For example, an event is on the 31/12/2015 and the period is one week, so there are two periods:24/12/2015 to 31/12/2015 and from 1/1/2016 to 7/1/2016, and we have three points to generate two lines: 24/12/2015, 31/12/2015, and 7/1/2016, so why the author say it is not testable.

Apart from that, why "difficult to distinguish between statistical noise and genuine deviations from the common trends" as well.

Comment: Can you describe what the three points represent? I thought we had the simple 2x2 case?

Comment: @ThomasBilach For example, an event is on the 31/12/2015 and the period is one week, so there  are two periods:24/12/2015 to 31/12/2015 and from 1/1/2016 to 7/1/2016, and we have three points to generate two lines: 24/12/2015, 31/12/2015, and 7/1/2016

Comment: So to be clear, we only observe outcomes for one time period before the event?

Comment: Yes, it is what I understand from two-period DID definition